# How to make mod_rewrite redirect properly in a subdirectory without specifying the path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's my issue:

Let's say I have a website, `www.example.com`. I have an application `subdir` located in a subdirectory of that domain's document root:

`/home/example/public_html/subdir/`

`subdir` contains this `.htaccess`:

```
# Redirect trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /subdir/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It works. If I go to http://www.example.com/subdir/not_a_directory/ (obviously assuming `not_a_directory` is not a directory), I get redirected to http://www.example.com/subdir/not_a_directory which is what I want.

But I don't want to have to specify `subdir` in the rewrite rule or anywhere in the `.htaccess`. I want to be able to change my application's path without breaking anything. I tried the following...

```
# Redirect trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

But I get redirected to: http://www.example.com/home/example/public_html/subdir/not_a_directory

I kind of understand why that happens (a relative path for the rewrite rule returns a file system path, whereas an absolute or root-absolute path returns a URL), but I cannot figure out how to achieve what I'm looking for.

Isn't there any way to have the capture group in `RewriteRule` include the `subdir` part of the path? I also tried setting `RewriteBase /` but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Rewrite rules confuse me a lot, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule without specifying `subdir` anywhere in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.+)/$
RewriteRule /$ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Capturing path from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` allows us to capture full URI path.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I noticed that `REQUEST_URI` included `subdir` but I didn't realize I could use a capture group within a RewriteCond (or rather, forgot that I could). Two more questions: 1. I imagine I can replace `RewriteRule /$` by `RewriteRule ^` as the second RewriteCond will already only rewrite URLs that end with a slash, is that correct? 2. Why the NE (noescape) flag?

Comment: Yes `RewriteRule ^` is perfectly fine here and `NE` is to avoid some special characters in URL getting encoded.

Comment: Is there a case where we wouldn't want `NE`?

Comment: I haven't come across any case when using `NE` has caused any harm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this location for rewritebase

```
RewriteBase subdir/
```

Comment: OP wrote: `I don't want to have to specify subdir in the rewrite rule or anywhere in the .htaccess`